# Get C# code from Unity apk

Tags: unity, c#, android, il2cpp

[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manojbhatt.cubiks)
is the app I built using Unity. The current version of the app is 8. I was stupid enough to lose the code for version 8. Now, I only have code till version 7. [This](https://github.com/manojbhatt101010/cubiks) is the code which doesn't have the changes I made in version 8. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16rBxCch_k7Y6A-1JsIaGaW6JkpmYVqdU/view?usp=sharing) is the APK file for version 8 of the app. I tried to get the C# code using this APK file by following tutorials on the internet but I couldn't. Can anyone please help me get the C# code?

NOTE: Scripting backend used was IL2CPP

Comment: *"I tried to get the C# code using this APK file by following tutorials on the internet but I couldn't."* Which tutorial did you use, and at which step did you encounter what kind of problem?

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorial actually. Some of them are for web version, some are for android studio, others are paid softwares.

Comment: [I'm finding a lot of leads with a quick search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+il2cpp+decompile+apk&ia=web), including GitHub projects that claim to automate the process. Want to try those and report back here with your progress?

Comment: Okay, I'll update after trying some

Comment: Using [This](https://github.com/djkaty/Il2CppInspector) project, I was able to get prototypes (variables, functions declarations) for C# scripts. I couldn't get actual code. Trying further.

Comment: I cannot progress further